# Disentangling Mysterious Wiring

Tags: electrical, wiring

hope everyone's having a good Sunday. Wanted to ask about the following: We moved into a condo that has a lot of wiring strewn throughout the walls. The previous owners had a wired home security system (which we now have an alternative for), had wired speakers in the ceiling, and all wiring is run through a conduit since that's required in Chicago.

What's the best way to disentangle all of this? Should we call an electrician and have them figure it out? Will they need to break open the wall to let us know what the random wires hanging out of our walls are?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: identify the two ends of each cable first ... it is up to you if an electrician should be called ... ask the electrician if they need to open up walls

Comment: Possible **big** complication: Low voltage wiring, as typically used for security systems and wired speakers (and also telephones and computer networks and intercoms), must **not** be run in the same conduit as 120V/240V wiring. In areas I'm familiar with, the low voltage stuff doesn't even need to be in conduit at all, but if it is in conduit, it must be separate from the 120V conduit.

Comment: Welcome to DIY.  This could be a great question.  Please take the [tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) and look at other questions that have good answers.  The fact that you do not know what the wires are for, and that they are in fact for different things, does not make them "entangled" or "strewn".  If you describe some of the wires, the parts that you see or do not see, and what you want to achieve, and ask a more technically precise question, you will get much better answers. ....

Comment: You probably want to know where various wires ENDS are exposed and what they are for or could be adapted to.  You probably don't care that much exactly how they are routed through walls, nor do you probably want to really "disentangle" them, which would involved tearing down all your condo walls!

Answer (score 2):

Well, low-voltage and line voltage should be in DIFFERENT conduits, so you can investigate yourself with relative easy and safety, and wiring in conduits should be running between accessible junction boxes, so there would be no need to break walls open. Nor any need to hire an electrician, and if you do, you should look for a "low-voltage electrician" i.e. someone familiar with common practices in low voltage wiring, not the guy who runs 120/240V stuff all day long and has (typically) little knowledge or interest in network/telcom/speaker wiring.*That happens to be my current day job, but I'm **not** looking to go to Chicago for it, so no self-interest there.*

While you can certainly get fancier and more expensive tools, a simple ohm-meter (or voltmeter plus a 9V battery, preferably with a resistor as well) will map wires perfectly well, and without the confusion that can happen when a "toner" bleeds onto poorly shielded neighboring wires. Somewhat slow but effective, good for the DIY approach.

Unless you plan to re-use the wires, the joy of conduit is that you can simply remove them, and map the conduit end-points, and then re-use the conduit for whatever you actually want to run to those locations, if anything.

Or you can simply leave it there without issue if you don't have plans that involve using the wiring, or the conduit paths, at this time.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if the conduit was competently done, all ends of the conduit pipes will be at accessible access covers (and most access covers have an outlet or switch).

Now, the #1 blunder I would expect to see here is someone putting data cables in power conduits.  That is a serious code violation.  That's super easy to correct, just remove the non-power cables.

Fiber-optic cables which have no conductive parts are allowed in power conduits.